# TabBar scrolling button moves down when zoom out

Tags: extjs

I have a tabbar in ExtJS with many tabs and I get scroll arrows on the left and right side on my tabbar. [image]
When I changing scale of web-page to 90%, right scroll arrow moves down to grid[image]
This bug appears in GoogleChrome, in FireFox is everything ok. What problem may be?

Comment: Inspect the arrow elements and the tab container, it might have some margins set. If it does, override it in your custom CSS file.

Comment: Hi Oxidizer, have you found a solution for this issue? I'm seeing the same problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

OK, we were able to solve this issue with some workaround css. It's ugly, but it gets the job done:

```css
 div.x-box-scroller-right {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    left: inherit !important;
    top: inherit !important;
}
```